# How to determine auto renewal preference change in Microsoft Store Subscription purchases through GetSubscriptionsForUser API?

Tags: windows, uwp, in-app-purchase, azure-active-directory, windows-store

We want to use this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user to be called from a renewal job to identify if the user's subscription has been renewed or not as expected to extend the license in our system. We want to detect the following scenarios:

1. User's subscription is renewed successfully for the next cycle.
2. User's subscription failed to renew successfully because of billing failure (Current Active)
3. User's subscription failed to renew successfully because of billing failure (Past expiration)
4. User opted out of renewal and the subscription expired.
5. User opted out of next renewal but current subscription is active.

We can determine the states 1-4 as per the documentation but how to determine for #5. We have the following understanding for the four states, based on the value of recurrenceState property:

1. User's subscription is renewed successfully for the next cycle - `Active`
2. User's subscription failed to renew successfully because of billing failure (Current Active) - `InDunning`
3. User's subscription failed to renew successfully because of billing failure (Past expiration) - `Failed`
4. User opted out of renewal and the subscription expired - `InActive`
5. User opted out of next renewal but current subscription is active - ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response includes a `autoRenew` field. If the `autoRenew` field is set to `false` **AND** state is `Active` it results into the #5 scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, scenario 5 is equivalent to: The subscription is active and the user is entitled to use the services in the current cycle. The subscription does not reach the terminal status at this time.

The state should not be changed whether auto-renew option is turned on or off. So the state of scene 5 is `Active` as well.

Comment: I understand that the status will still be `Active` but I am looking for something that will let me know that the user has opted out of next renewal so that some offer can be pushed out to them.

Comment: Did you check Item cancellationDate(The date and time the user's subscription was cancelled) at the bottom of the Response body ?